# How do I return multiple values using annotations?

Tags: python, python-3.x, annotations

I recently discovered [Function Annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/) in Python 3.x and the usefulness they may have.

I installed the module `typeannotations`to allow for type checking of the parameters and return types.

Working Example:

```
from annotation.typed import typechecked    

@typechecked
def test_func(arg1: int) -> int:
    return arg1   

print(test_func(1))

>>> 1
```

Broken Example, raising `TypeError` as it should.

```
from annotation.typed import typechecked

@typechecked
def test_func(arg1: int) -> str:
    return arg1   

print(test_func(1))

>>>TypeError: Incorrect return type
```

However I have not been able to figure out how to use `typechecker` to return multiple values

```
from annotation.typed import typechecked

@typechecked
def test_func(arg1: str, arg2: str) -> (str, str):
    return arg1, arg2

print(test_func('hello', 'world'))
```

I am passing in two `str` and returning a list with two `str`, however it raises

```
TypeError: Incorrect return type
```

How might I go about returning multiple values this way?

Comment: Nice Question. Can you check if  `-> tuple:` works?

Comment: @BhargavRao, tuple will work but not sure if the OP want to be more specific or if you actually can

Comment: @PadraicCunningham AFAIK type-hinting (Pep483) doesn't mention a word about nested return values. So I guess the OP needs to do some client side type checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is **no**.

The long answer is **yes** with some coding:

If you are comfortable modifying the source code (which I've had to do on several occasions), you could implement your own way of doing this.

Keep in mind, this is just a quick bit of code, I'm sure there is a more efficient way of doing this, however this will give you want you are looking for:

In the `typed.py` file, find the `_check_return_type()` function and add change it to the following:

```
def _check_return_type(signature, return_value):
    """Check that the return value of a function matches the signature."""
    annotation = signature.return_annotation

    if annotation is EMPTY_ANNOTATION:
        annotation = AnyType

    # If the return type is a tuple of typed values, and the length is greater than 1 (to prevent the actual tuple return type)
    if isinstance(annotation, tuple) and len(annotation) > 1:
        for p, a in zip(return_value, annotation):
            if not isinstance(p, a):
                raise TypeError('Incorrect return type: {} ({} required)'.format(type(p), a))

    else:
        if not isinstance(return_value, annotation):
            raise TypeError('Incorrect return type')
    return return_value
```

This will check each value that is being returned in the order of the tuple that you have set.

Now, if you don't want to modify the original source code, you can write your own function and invoke it like this:

```
def typechecked(target):
    import inspect
    import functools

    @functools.wraps(target)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        signature = inspect.signature(target)
        params = target(*args, **kwargs)

        for p, a in zip(params, signature.return_annotation):
            if not isinstance(p, a):
                raise TypeError('Incorrect return type: {} ({} required)'.format(type(p), a))
        return params

    return wrapper
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This solution works nicely, thanks! I'd rather write more code than modify the source. This does, however, break if no return types are given, but I do not see a case where I will not have a return type

Comment: I only modify the core code if necessary. Sometimes it's necessary, but if there is a workaround, I'm all for it.